# Oauth runkeeper returns 1

Tags: php, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I got my code setup to connect with the authentication system of runkeeper.
I have this weird issue of the token returned always being one.

I've struggling with it for 8hours now. I messed around with kinda all possible solutions. Also already used fopen and get file contents instead of curl

Anyone who sees what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Runkeeper {

private $client_id= '89ede033eb224a1b85b000bb35779db9';
private $client_secret ='***';
private $auth_url ='https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize';
private $access_token_url = 'https://runkeeper.com/apps/token';
private $de_auth_url = 'https://runkeeper.com/apps/de-authorize';
private $response_type = 'code';
private $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/vicoin/index.php/auth/runkeeper_reg';

public function __construct() {




}
public function connect(){
$req = "https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize?client_id=89ede033eb224a1b85b000bb35779db9&redirect_uri=http://localhost/vicoin/index.php/auth/runkeeper_reg&response_type=code";

return $req; 

}

public function callback($codeR){
  $grant_type ='authorization_code'; 
  $code = $codeR;
  $client_id = '89ede033eb224a1b85b000bb35779db9';
  $client_secret = '**';
  $redirect_uri2 = "http://localhost/vicoin/index.php/auth/runkeeper_reg"; 
  /*
    $url = 'https://runkeeper.com/app/token';
    $data = array('grant_type' => $grant_type, 'code' => $code, 'client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri2);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = fopen($url,'rb',false,$context);
    //var_dump($http_response_header);
    var_dump($result);
    //print_r($data);
    return $result;
   */

  $params = http_build_query(array(
        'grant_type'    =>  'authorization_code',
        'code'      =>  $codeR,
        'client_id' =>  $this->client_id,
        'client_secret' =>  $this->client_secret,
        'redirect_uri'  =>  ($redirect_uri2 == '' ? $this->redirect_uri : $redirect_uri2)
    ));
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL     =>  $this->access_token_url,
        CURLOPT_POST        =>  true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  $params,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>  true
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); /* Added to avoid "error :SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK" */
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $response     = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $decoderesponse = json_decode($response);
    if ($decoderesponse == null) {
        $this->api_last_error = "getRunkeeperToken: bad response";
        return(false);
    }
    elseif (!isset($decoderesponse->error)) {
        if (isset($decoderesponse->access_token)) {
            $this->access_token = $decoderesponse->access_token;
        }
        if (isset($decoderesponse->token_type)) {
            $this->token_type = $decoderesponse->token_type;
        }
        return(true);
    }
    elseif ($decoderesponse->error == 'invalid_grant') {
        header('Location: https://runkeeper.com/app/token?response_type=code&client_id='.$this->client_id.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($this->redirect_uri), true, 302);
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $this->api_last_error = "getRunkeeperToken: ".$decoderesponse->error;
        return(false);

    }
  var_dump($http_response_header);
```

}

}